# I can't update apps with new Apple ID

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id

I used to have an old Apple ID, and I have a specific paid app I purchased with that ID. I now have a new Apple ID, and I wanted to update the paid app from the old Apple ID with the new Apple ID.

I am wondering if I deleted the app, would it show up as "purchased" on my new Apple ID?

Answer (score 1):

No - purchases are not transferable, but you could set up your new account as family share and if the purchases are eligible for sharing, you would then get to use the new appleID and password to download for free the "purchase" from the 'family member"

Answer (score 0):

If the app was purchased under the old Apple ID, it's considered "owned by" that Apple ID. Updates, redownloads, etc must be done under that Apple ID. There is no way to transfer ownership to a different Apple ID. The only option you have to get it "owned by" your new Apple ID is to delete it, and then re-purchase it under your new Apple ID (and yes, this does mean paying for it again, along with any in-app purchases). Sorry about that...